# Paragraph doesn't hide on click

Tags: jquery

This Is Default

```
<p id="pp">
THIS DUDE IS HIDING
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#pp').hide('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to hide a paragraph id=pp but on button click nothing happen, i also passed function name at button click but nothin happen.

Comment: The HTML is relevant as well.

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    This Is Default<input id="btn" type="button" value="button"  />
    <p id="pp">
    THIS DUDE IS HIDING
   </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#pp').hide('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: Have you checked if `$('#btn')` and `$('#pp')` return elements you think they do?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is you <p> tag closed? Is jQuery loaded correctly? Is the click function executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work if your HTML structure is correct. E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#pp').hide('slow');
        return false;
    });
});//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="pp">THIS DUDE IS HIDING</p>
<button id="btn">Hide the paragraph</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update** It works fine as well with the HTML from your comment:

```
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; 
<head runat="server"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#pp').hide('slow'); 
        return false;
    }); 
}); 
</script> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <div><input id="btn" type="button" value="button" /></div> 
        <p id="pp"> PARAGRAPH IS HERE ...... </p> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: @user614946 You have to show the generated HTML source if you expect more help.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#pp').hide('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
    
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="button" /></div>
        <p id="pp">
        PARAGRAPH IS HERE ......
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
DONT WORK!

Comment: @user614946 - You can edit your original question and provide further info there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

It's something with the HTML. Compare your ASP.NET code to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbncL/) which is based on your sample. I would recommend making sure that the JS is loaded from the head element, not the HTML body.

You should also run a test in Firefox and see if you get any JavaScript errors in the Firefox error console.